# resultado de consulta de la api, almacenar en otra variable en javaScript

Tags: javascript, api, axios

Buenas tengo una consulta a una api mediante axios. Deseo almacenar el resultado de la consulta en otra variable que sea consultado mas adelante.

```
const obtenervalor = async() => {
  const respuesta = await axios.get(apibuy)
  console.log(respuesta.data.price)
}
obtenervalor();
```

deseo agregar el valor en una nueva variable llamada precio

Comment: Declara la variable `respuesta` afuera de la función `obtenervalor`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer de esta forma, pero dependiendo de lo que vayas a hacer con este precio puede que necesites usar una promesa, pero por lo pronto de esta forma puedes almacenar el valor

```js
const obtenervalor = async() => {
  const respuesta = await axios.get(apibuy)
  return respuesta.data.price
}

var precio = obtenervalor();
```

Answer (score 0):

Formalmente, puedes declarar la respuesta en el scope global, y acceder a ella desde fuera de la función, pero es una mala idea.

En el siguiente ejemplo `obtenervalor` devuelve una promesa (como toda función async) que se resuelve luego de un intervalo que no controlamos (como toda promesa, diría yo), con el mismo argumento que le pasamos. O sea es un `echo` con demora aleatoria.

Si llamamos a la función tres veces ¿Cuál es el valor de la variable?

```js
let variableGlobal;

async function generarValor(tag) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(tag), Math.random() * 1500)
  })
}

const obtenerValor = async(tag) => {
  variableGlobal = await generarValor(tag)
}

async function capturaResultado() {
  Promise.all([
    obtenerValor('primero'),
    obtenerValor('segundo'),
    obtenerValor('tercero')
  ]).then(() => {
    console.log({
      variableGlobal
    })
  })
}
capturaResultado();
```

La última en resolverse sobreescribe la variable global. Por eso el refrán:

> ### “promesa que resuelve último, resuelve mejor” <sup>tm</sup>

Ahora imagínate debuggeando en una aplicación compleja dónde corchos se está modificando el valor de la variable que todos manipulan.

Lo correcto sería, en cambio, que el valor que te interesa provenga única y específicamente de la función que invocaste, y  distintos llamados sean independientes entre sí, sacando los nocivos side-effects de la mesa.

```js
async function generarValor(tag) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(tag), Math.random() * 1500)
  })
}

const obtenerValor = async(tag) => {
  return await generarValor(tag)
}

async function capturaResultado() {
  obtenerValor('primero').then(primerValor => console.log({
    primerValor
  }))
  const segundoValor = await obtenerValor('segundo')
  console.log({
    segundoValor
  })
}
capturaResultado();
```

En ese ejemplo capturo un resultado con la sintaxis `Promise...then` y otro con `async...await`. No tengo idea en qué orden responderán, pero sí tengo seguridad de cuál resultado corresponde a qué variable.